# How can I get fidelity of a gate from randomized benchmarking?

Tags: fidelity, clifford-group, randomised-benchmarking, gate-fidelity

I [found](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emartinisgroup/theses/Kelly2015.pdf) (page 33) the method of finding fidelity from fit by "interleaved and reference decay" according to the sequence fidelity formula: $$F_{ref}=Ap_{ref}^{m}+B,$$
where $p_{ref}^{m}$ is sequence decay.

But if we look at the following datasets:

[image: Fidelities]

we can find that the reference sequence fidelity curve is close to $1$ and the other curves corresponding to the gates - around $0.998-0.999$ (which corresponds to decay $p_{gate}$).

How could it be that the difference between interleaved and reference decays is around $0.999$?

Comment: Can I extract fidelity from gate error: $r_{gate}=(1-p_{gate}/p_{ref})(d-1)/d$ with $d=2^n$ and fidelity will be 1-$r_{gate}$?